# DNX SDK version "dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-preview2-003131" failed to install

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

I am not understanding why am I getting above mentioned error while loading some new pulled project from tfs. Even though I have Microsoft DNX folder in my explorer it asks me to install DNX SDK and when I install it fails.
 I tried updating visual studio also but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What version of `.Net Core` are you using? What versions of VS have you installed?

Comment: Hi @Ignas, I use VS 15 and issue resolved for me by installing DotNetCore-VS2015-PreviewTools. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since I use VS 2015, above mentioned issue resolved for me by downloading specific .Net Core version from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546 . It gives you DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe

You can get other related .Net Core SDKs from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

If you have VS 2017, you don't need to install .Net Core SDK explicitly. You get it by default in VS 17.

Cheers!